# How to remove the numbers, char, spl char before comma(,)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Here I have the map location with latitude and longitude,
[image]

Here I don't want to print that lat long i.e. I want to remove everything before the ,   . I am using explode function, but my code is  working here.

Comment: Please do share some code which you have tried so far!

Comment: I am getting the location directly from google maps GPS location. I just took in a variable $location and printing them

Comment: Ex: i got location like this  17°20'15.1N 78°32'07.6E, 8-24/5, Inner Ring Rd, Mytripuram, Karmanghat, Hyderabad, Telangana 500079, India...

Comment: I want to print  8-24/5, Inner Ring Rd, Mytripuram, Karmanghat, Hyderabad, Telangana 500079, India    only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**  try with `explode` by setting `limit` as third parameter

*If limit is set and positive, the returned array will contain a maximum of limit elements with the last element containing the rest of string.*

Working demo : https://eval.in/1022185

```
$string = "17°20'15.1N 78°32'07.6E, 8-24/5, Inner Ring Rd, Mytripuram, Karmanghat, Hyderabad, Telangana 500079, India";

$arr = explode(',', $string, 2);

echo $arr[1];
```

**Output :**

```
8-24/5, Inner Ring Rd, Mytripuram, Karmanghat, Hyderabad, Telangana 500079, India
```

for more : http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: OP also says he tried explode, maybe you should include what you done differently than OP?

Comment: Its displaying 'array' only

Comment: surely you doing something wrong,have you seen my demo example https://eval.in/1022185 in my answer

Comment: <dt>Map Location :</dt>
  
  <dd><a href="#"><?php 
  
  $remove[] = '"'; 

$row_b['location'] = str_replace( $remove, "", $row_b['location']);

  echo $row_b['location']; 
  
 
  ?></a></dd>     here is my code in dynamic

Comment: i added as    echo explode(",",$row_breed['location'],2);

Comment: see my answer how i am echoing variable, `$arr = explode(",",$row_breed['location'],2); echo $arr[1];`

Comment: should be like this : `<dt>Map Location :</dt> 
<dd>
  <a href="#">
    <?php 
      $location = explode(',', $row_b['location'], 2);
      echo $location[1]; 
    ?>
  </a>
</dd> `

Comment: Superb!!!! Its working!!! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = "17°20'15.1N 78°32'07.6E, 8-24/5, Inner Ring Rd, Mytripuram, Karmanghat, Hyderabad, Telangana 500079, India";
var split = string.split(",")
var a = split.slice(1,split.length-1);
console.log(a.join());
```

As described by you, you can split the string using string.split(",") and then slice it from index 1 and then rejoin the array to form a new string.

Comment: <dt>Map Location :</dt> <dd><a href="#"><?php $remove[] = '"'; $row_b['location'] = str_replace( $remove, "", $row_b['location']); echo $row_b['location']; ?></a></dd>    how to manipulate this one

Comment: Put my code in a js function and call the method from your php code